# What is a sub $150 camera with a fast response time?

Tags: equipment-recommendation

I want to buy a cheap camera and the only real criteria is that response time should be fast - i.e. when you press the button, the shot is taken quickly.  I have owned cameras in the past where there is a noticeable delay after pressing the button.

This camera will be my young son's first camera so mainly it needs to be cheap but still usable i.e. not junk.

Nice to have but not required features:

- camera release date as recent as possible - I'd prefer not to be buying a
  camera based on old technology
- wifi
- standard size usb port

Comment: What have you researched so far? Have you tried any cameras in your local camera store / big box retailer that are approximately at your price point, and if so, how did you feel about their shutter response? What type of camera are you looking for – compact point-and-shoot; or bridge camera; or full interchangeable lens camera (DSLR or mirrorless)?

Comment: Probably an used DLSR camera, one that you can test, of a photographer that lives on the same city as you. Old technology? If they record on a SD card you are ok.

Answer (score 3):

**There isn't one.**

Minimal shutter delay typically requires a dSLR. Or a film camera. :)  Some mirrorless bodies have shorter shutter delay than P&S cameras, but depending on the model, it can still be noticeably longer than with a dSLR.  And relatively new dSLRs don't come for $150. And wi-fi is a relatively recent feature.

A used dSLR/film camera is probably the only path for what you want, and even then, your budget is kinda ridiculously low.

Understand that for a new dSLR setup, you typically need roughly $1000: $500 for the camera and $500 for the lenses.  Adjust used prices accordingly.

I'd recommend giving up almost-new & wi-fi; giving up minimal shutter delay; or quadrupling your budget.

As for a "standard size USB port", nearly all cameras have either USB mini-b or Micro USB-b ports. Both of which are standards. I've never seen a digital camera with a USB A-type port.  But a lot of us use *card readers* to transfer images from a camera to a computer, not a USB cable. Only a handful of digital cameras charge via the USB port--most typically come with a dedicated charger for the battery pack.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, it does not exists at that price point with the features your are requesting.

A fast "response" time is something that cost money because it is somewhat related to the auto-focus system; and a fast auto-focus system cost money.

And having a fast auto-focus cost money.

At that price point, I'd go to a large surface store (walmart, target...) and get a entry-level "bridge" camera; this will have plenty of features for your kid to have fun with and learn photography.